# Manipulating Clojure closures?

Tags: clojure, closures

I'm new with Clojure and I'm working on creating a simple bank account function that returns a closure.  I have figured out how to initialize the variables, but I can't seem to figure out how to manipulate the balance.  I would like to create a :withdrawal and :deposit to perform their respective functions, but I can't seem to figure out how.

```
(defn account 
  [name initial-balance password]
  (fn [a & args] 
    (condp = a
      :name name
      :balance initial-balance
      :authenticate (= password (first args)))))
```

Comment: Instead of `condp`, you might want to use [`case`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/case), which is a little more succinct (but only works when you're only comparing against compile-time constants, like keywords).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Clojure idioms usually discourage mutable state. When you do want to mutate something like your bank account balance, the usual way to do that would be with a thread-safe [`atom`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/atom). Here's an example:

```
(defn account 
  [name initial-balance password]
  (let [balance (atom initial-balance)]
    (fn [a & args] 
      (case a
        :name name
        :balance @balance
        :deposit (swap! balance + (first args))
        :withdraw (swap! balance - (first args))
        :authenticate (= password (first args))))))
```

Comment: so If I create a person like so, 

    `(def person (account "name" 1000 "password"))`

 how do I use the `:deposit`?  I tried 

`(person :deposit 200)` and I received an error.

Comment: @Busch, what error are you getting? The posted code worked for me. Try evaluating `account` again, maybe an older version stuck around.

Comment: @Busch - I tested the code before I posted it, so it should work. I also just tried pasting my code into a fresh REPL, and then pasting your code from your comment, and it works fine. I think jbm is right. You should just try it again in a fresh REPL session.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach which still represents the account as a closure but doesn't mutate `balance`. Instead, `deposit` and `withdraw` return a new account closure.

```
(defn account
  [name balance password]
  (fn [msg & args]
    (case msg
      :name name
      :balance balance
      :deposit (account name (- balance (first args)) password)
      :withdraw (account name (+ balance (first args)) password)
      :authenticate (= password (first args)))))
```

Since e.g. `(person :deposit 50)` returns a new closure rather than the new balance you would need to follow it up with a `:balance` call/message to see what the resulting balance was.

```
(def person (account "name" 100 "password"))

(person :deposit 50) ; returns a new closure
;=>  #<user$account$fn__85647 user$account$fn__85647@884327>

(person :balance) ; our original `person` still has its original balance
;=> 100

((person :deposit 50) :balance) ; but a new closure can have a new balance
;=> 150
```

Comment: +1 It's good to have the function approach here too. Even if the OP was going for something with mutation, hopefully seeing the functional example will help him think more about using immutable data structures next time.